# automatically refreshing a page in rails to get the users current spotify song

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, spotify

In my app I need to update details on a page when the song in a users playlist changes. My current solution is to use javascript's setInterval on an ajax request to the page. Which results in a 500 error. Is there a better solution? Does anyone know if theres something in the spotify api that already handles this?

web_player.html.erb (view that needs to update automatically)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<% @playlists_new.each do |t_info| %>
  <% if t_info[0][0].eql? @current_song %>
    <body>
      <%= link_to 'back', {:controller => "players", :action => "index", :user => @user.to_hash} %>
      <h1>Player</h1>
      <div id="player">
        <div id="track-info">
          <img id="track-cover" src=<%=@player_response['item']['album']['images'][0]['url'].to_s%>></img>
          <h3 id="track-name"><%= @current_song %></h3>
          <h3 id="artist-name"><%= @player_response['item']['artists'][0]['name'] %></h3>
        </div>

        <div id="memories">
          <h3 id="text-memory"><%= t_info[1][0] %></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    <body>

    <style>
      body {
        background:
          linear-gradient(
            rgba(30, 32, 35, 0.45),
            rgba(30, 32, 35, 0.45)
          ),
          url(<%= t_info[2][0].to_s %>);
      }
    </style>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
  setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "web_player",
      data: {
        playlist_info: <%= raw(@playlists).html_safe  %>,
        user: <%= raw(@user.to_json).html_safe %>,
      },
      dataType: 'html'
   })
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

players_controller.rb

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

class PlayersController < ApplicationController

  protect_from_forgery except: :web_player

  def index
    params.require(:user).permit!
    @playlists = Hash.new
    @user = RSpotify::User.new(params[:user]);
    #all tracks with a memory attached
    @tracks = Track.where(:username => @user.display_name).order(:playlist_name)
    #we need to organize the tracks and memories by playlist
    @tracks.each do |t|
      if @playlists[t.playlist_name].nil?
        @playlists[t.playlist_name] = []
      end
      #get playlist URI !!
      @user.playlists.each do |p|
        if p.name.eql? t.playlist_name
          @playlist_uri = p.uri
        end
      end

      @playlists[t.playlist_name] << [t.title, t.memory, t.imageurl, @playlist_uri]
    end

    @player_response = RSpotify.resolve_auth_request(@user.display_name, "me/player/")
    @current_song = @player_response
    if @current_song.nil?
      @current_song = " "
    else
      @current_song = @player_response['item']['name']
    end
  end
  #plays playlist
  def play
    params.require(:user).permit!
    @user = RSpotify::User.new(params[:user]);
    @uri = URI('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play')
    #request body tells spotify what playlist to play
    @body = {
      "context_uri": params[:playlist_uri]
    }.to_json
    #headers
    req = Net::HTTP::Put.new(@uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + @user.credentials['token'].to_s})
    req.body = @body
    http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    response = http.start {|h|
      h.request(req)
    }
    sleep 1.5
    #redirecting to new action so the user can refresh the web player and not restart the playlist
    redirect_to :action => "web_player", :user => @user.to_hash, :playlist_info => params[:playlist_info]
  end

  def web_player
    params.require(:user).permit!
    @user = RSpotify::User.new(params[:user]);
    #get currrent song playing to decide what memory to display
    @player_response = RSpotify.resolve_auth_request(@user.display_name, "me/player/")
    @current_song = @player_response
    if @current_song.nil?
      @current_song = " "
    else
      @current_song = @player_response['item']['name']
    end

    @playlists = params[:playlist_info]
    @playlists_new = []
    #uhh so the playlists hash gets fucked so i'm rebuilding it here hehehe
    (@playlists.length/4).times do |t|
      @playlists_new << [@playlists[(t * 4)], @playlists[(t * 4) + 1], @playlists[(t * 4) + 2]]
    end
  end
end
```

Also, this is a good request being generated by the play action:

```
http://localhost:3000/players/web_player?playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=Guilty&playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=farted+eheh&playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=&playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=spotify%3Aplaylist%3A23zfZIyQInLuAyxZzv4taL&playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=Lissoms&playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=farting+large+%3E%3A%29&playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fclipart-library.com%2Fdata_images%2F80305.png&playlist_info%5B%5D%5B%5D=spotify%3Aplaylist%3A23zfZIyQInLuAyxZzv4taL&user%5Bbirthdate%5D=&user%5Bcountry%5D=&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Bexpires%5D=true&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Bexpires_at%5D=1554571172&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Brefresh_token%5D=AQBuXWgqyvHVsvV0L138RtuvTmc8gKX-PMxvBQ3ovQVyR_40wlPRjvskR6E3s3btEctUYtx44HKMq22Xen7Le_eLg5w70VXl_YTMX-fmCGGnqJqLLWGXAaXrRyqZSBt1mdu2wg&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Btoken%5D=BQDoUpwrQUsIrc1qDksp--ilhqV6sC0CBnG2e2AZaY1DGj-wgHAWtvnOxkrebfw2C2r5QT-GnAQtJe7sAdH6lc4HF-edb6JnXzy-GZgeIwfYVTugzwNgVQ9uLCTkztPQQu86IsRrEVbtWvdlufVem-S47ms99ZWcujS2fz1Jb6aZGj3_MVtgeicdN5XRuA4zRzYUQoaWxbng_KO9muuUofDr&user%5Bdisplay_name%5D=jakeherman-3&user%5Bemail%5D=jakeherman%40outlook.com&user%5Bexternal_urls%5D%5Bspotify%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fuser%2Fjakeherman-3&user%5Bfollowers%5D%5Bhref%5D=&user%5Bfollowers%5D%5Btotal%5D=15&user%5Bhref%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.spotify.com%2Fv1%2Fusers%2Fjakeherman-3&user%5Bid%5D=jakeherman-3&user%5Bimages%5D%5B%5D%5Bheight%5D=&user%5Bimages%5D%5B%5D%5Burl%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fprofile-images.scdn.co%2Fimages%2Fuserprofile%2Fdefault%2Ffa01ec91c49ec1bfc76c3b32b7b7260af83b3903&user%5Bimages%5D%5B%5D%5Bwidth%5D=&user%5Bproduct%5D=&user%5Btype%5D=user&user%5Buri%5D=spotify%3Auser%3Ajakeherman-3
```

And this is the bad (500 error) request being generated by the ajax method:

```
http://localhost:3000/players/web_player?playlist_info%5B0%5D%5B%5D=Guilty&playlist_info%5B1%5D%5B%5D=farted+eheh&playlist_info%5B2%5D%5B%5D=&playlist_info%5B3%5D%5B%5D=spotify%3Aplaylist%3A23zfZIyQInLuAyxZzv4taL&playlist_info%5B4%5D%5B%5D=Lissoms&playlist_info%5B5%5D%5B%5D=farting+large+%3E%3A)&playlist_info%5B6%5D%5B%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fclipart-library.com%2Fdata_images%2F80305.png&playlist_info%5B7%5D%5B%5D=spotify%3Aplaylist%3A23zfZIyQInLuAyxZzv4taL&user%5Bbirthdate%5D=&user%5Bcountry%5D=&user%5Bdisplay_name%5D=jakeherman-3&user%5Bemail%5D=jakeherman%40outlook.com&user%5Bfollowers%5D%5Bhref%5D=&user%5Bfollowers%5D%5Btotal%5D=15&user%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D%5Bheight%5D=&user%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D%5Burl%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fprofile-images.scdn.co%2Fimages%2Fuserprofile%2Fdefault%2Ffa01ec91c49ec1bfc76c3b32b7b7260af83b3903&user%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D%5Bwidth%5D=&user%5Bproduct%5D=&user%5Bexternal_urls%5D%5Bspotify%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fuser%2Fjakeherman-3&user%5Bhref%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.spotify.com%2Fv1%2Fusers%2Fjakeherman-3&user%5Bid%5D=jakeherman-3&user%5Btype%5D=user&user%5Buri%5D=spotify%3Auser%3Ajakeherman-3&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Bexpires%5D=true&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Bexpires_at%5D=1554571172&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Brefresh_token%5D=AQBuXWgqyvHVsvV0L138RtuvTmc8gKX-PMxvBQ3ovQVyR_40wlPRjvskR6E3s3btEctUYtx44HKMq22Xen7Le_eLg5w70VXl_YTMX-fmCGGnqJqLLWGXAaXrRyqZSBt1mdu2wg&user%5Bcredentials%5D%5Btoken%5D=BQDoUpwrQUsIrc1qDksp--ilhqV6sC0CBnG2e2AZaY1DGj-wgHAWtvnOxkrebfw2C2r5QT-GnAQtJe7sAdH6lc4HF-edb6JnXzy-GZgeIwfYVTugzwNgVQ9uLCTkztPQQu86IsRrEVbtWvdlufVem-S47ms99ZWcujS2fz1Jb6aZGj3_MVtgeicdN5XRuA4zRzYUQoaWxbng_KO9muuUofDr
```

Answer (score 0):

In the script in the web player view I am calling location.reload() on a 3 second interval. A more efficient way to do this could be to get the length of the current song and change the interval to the track length I guess. But that doesn't account for if the user was to skip the song.

```
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
   location.reload();
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Not necessarily happy with this solution, but it works for now.

Comment: As you say you could set the reloading time to the track length and also add event listeners to the controls to handle the user changing/pausing tracks. Maybe add one event listener to the control panel container and use event delegation.